# Why all my screenshots in Google Play App (App only) are pixelated

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I just published my new app on Google Play Store for internal testing. I attached the screenshot images and they all look great on on laptops web browsers and mobile web browsers, but they are terribly pixelated on Google Play Store App. I have tried high resolution PNG, high resolution JPG, low resolution PNG, low resolution JPG, I even bought mockup version with my app screenshot in it, but it is pixelated too after upload to Google Play store.

Resolution is 1440x2880 for JPG and PNG format. I also tried resolutions as 1080x1920, 640x1136 and 866x1526, but it didn't help either.

It has great screenshots quality on laptop web browser and also on mobile devices when you visiting google play store over web browser. Images are pixelated only on Google Play store app.

I sent a link to one of my testers and he confirmed, screenshots are also pixelated on his device in Google Play store app.

Google requirements for screenshots are as follows:

> Requirements to publish your Store Listing, you must provide a minimum of 2 screenshots.
>
> JPEG or 24-bit PNG (no alpha)
>
> Minimum dimension: 320px
>
> Maximum dimension: 3840px
>
> The maximum dimension of your screenshot can't be more than twice as long as the minimum dimension.

Please see attached images bellow:

[ORIGINAL UPLOADED SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkxQS.jpg)

[SCREENSHOT IN GOOGLE PLAY STORE APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr4d9.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This is called compression, not a resolution issue. PNG have a loseless compression, but google does not - they will compress your source if it is exceeding their limits.

Try to reduce colours, do not load super-high-resolution images as they will be compressed harder.

Check https://tinypng.com/ to compress images, sometimes results are great and files are much much smaller.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it didn't help at all. Tinypng did compress my image from 863 KB to 151 KB but it is still pixelated after uploading it to Google Play Store. No difference from previous images. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you share the link to this app with the screenshot issue?

Comment: @PeterKundis Did you find a solution?

Comment: @GayanWeerakutti Nope. It seems it happens for every other app there too and people should use simple images with no gradient colors.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using 24-bit colors with no transparency spec:

[image: google guide line]

You can use tool in android studio to make screenshots.